# How to assign address of function pointer according to char*?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am writing a C program that could be simplified if I manage to do something like this:

```
int (*func)(int);
char* str= "adder";
func = str;
func(2);
```

I create a function pointer, a char*, and I try to assign the name of the function to the pointer through that char*. In this example, the adder(int) function exists.

Is this actually possible?

I know the standard way of doing it would just be func = adder;, but that will not solve it.

Thanks a lot!

Antonio

Comment: There are things that get you close to this, but you cannot, say, take a string and use it to define which function to call by name.  If you tell us what you really want to do (the core problem), perhaps we can help you find the *right* solution.

Comment: Hello Mark, I was basically trying to call a function depending on the arguments passed to the main function. I know I could do it comparing and checking with conditional structures, but I was hoping I could do it in a more efficient way. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering so fast. I've realized this is not something I can accomplish as easily as in the snippet I provide and I will try to go with the mapping technique shown below by R.. . Thanks again for your help!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a table like this:

```
static const struct {
    char *name;
    int (*func)(int);
} map[] = {
    { "adder", adder },
    /* ... */
    { 0, 0 }
}
```

And then use this code:

```
for (i=0; map[i].name && strcmp(map[i].name, str); i++);
if (map[i].func) y = map[i].func(x);
else /* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I think that leads me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't do what I think you think it should do. If you managed to converted `"adder"` into a function pointer, you'd be trying to execute the actual text as a function, not what you want. You can keep arrays of function pointers, you can also keep a mapping of text → function pointer. Beyond that, we need more info about what you're doing.

Comment: I was actually trying to call a function depending on the arguments passed to the program, without checking the different possibilities with a switch structure

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know is to put your function in a dynamic library and use [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) or your operating system's equivalent to get your function pointer.  Alternately, you would have to set up your own map from string to function pointer somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into setting up a map

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish something like this using dlls in windows and the [getprocaddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28VS.85%29.aspx) function but you will have to use only functions that have the same signature or keep some type of elaborate mapping.  What you are trying to do however requires additional infrastructure.  If your using c++ you could use a map to store a relationship between strings and fnptrs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm programming in plain C, in UNIX